# it has to be StackoverflowError or OOME

Tags: java

when I run below program

```
class Person{
     Person p;
     Person(){
         System.out.println("Hi");
         p = new Person();
     }
 }

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Person();
    }
}
```

it throws StackOverFlow error
but i expected it to be OOME, as we are working with object creation, not with any local method/variable or reference variable

Comment: Looks like you're trying to create a person object in the person class constructor and it looks like you're going in to an infinite loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are recursively and without a termination condition calling the `Person()` constructor, which places data on the stack (at least, the return address - the stack is not only used for local variables and parameters):

```
Person(){
    p = new Person();   // <<== Calls the Person() constructor, which again calls the Person() constructor, which again ...
}
```

Hence, you get a stack overflow error.

Theoretically, the compiler could see that this is a tail recursion and optimize out the method call, but this does not happen.

The `Person` objects themselves are created on the heap, but usually the heap is larger than the stack (at least by default), so the stack fills up earlier than the heap.

Try running the same application with different settings for the stack size and the maximum heap size, like

```
java -Xss128M -Xmx4M Person
```

and you will get an OOME instead of the stack overflow.

Comment: constructor places data on heap, as its part of object creation(which exists on heap), is this not the case ?

Comment: The object itself is created on the heap by `new`, but still the constructor invocation places at least the return address onto the stack. Usually the heap is larger than the stack, so the stack is filled up before the heap.

Answer (score 2):

Your expectation is not unwarranted.

There are two forces at work here:

- Object creation of person() on the heap
- Callstack enlargement via deep recursion

Which one of these 2 fails first is anyones guess, and highly depends on the settings for the JVM. Set your -Xmx to a very low value, and you will most probably get an OOMException first.

Comment: Callstack enlargement via deep recursion - means recursion will happens on Stack in general.

Answer (score 1):

Because its going in a infinite loop where Person constructor is again calling the constructor .

The stack has a limit and when it reaches the error happens.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html

Answer (score 0):

The reason is a recursion-invoke occured in the default constructor of Person().

At a deeper level of knowledge of JVM to explain this problem: the java virtual machine specification has ruled two situations of exception for java stack:

1. Java stack is allowed to expand automaticly, it'll throw
   OOM(OutOfMemory) error when it cann't apply for enough memory.
2. Java stack is constituted with stack frame, and each java method
   push a frame, it'll throw the StackOverflowError when the stack
   depth of the current thread is larger than the jvm's allowed.

Maybe help you:)